Mobile specific bot detection
I want to make sure my mobile app is resistant to bot attacks.
all I found where reCAPTCHA implementations for mobile apps which is not ideal since it is made for web browsers in mind. any help concerning this matter is greatly appreciated.
I would like to know how YOU fixed this problem.
